# Allow user to create databases, but only see those that they have access to

Tags: mysql, privileges

I have recently set up MySQL with several users, with each user having access to a set of databases. I'd like for users to be able to copy these databases so that they can back them up, but if I allow them the 'Create_priv' then they are able to see every database, not just the ones that they have permissiosn for (although users can't do anything on those for which they do not have permission, I'd like for them to not be visible at all).

Am I selecting the wrong privilege for this action?

Comment: Why would you allow creating database for backup purposes? That's what `mysqldump` was made for. Just make a dump of that database to a file…

Comment: @feeela - Thanks, but regardless of whether that is right or wrong, users still require the ability to do it. They may also need to set up new databases for new websites in the future. Thanks.